# Input onChange makes multiple re-renders

Tags: javascript, reactjs, multiple-input

I learn React and I faced some problems. I thought I understand controlled components, but well, it seems otherwise. Could you explain me, why after onChange event I receive props for rest Input components? If I want add label that depends on *this.pops.name* it gets messy (because of props I see in console.log). I would be grateful for explanation.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class Input extends Component {
  handleChange = (e) => {
    this.props.onInputChange(e);
  };
  chooseLabel = (props) => {
    let { name } = props;
    console.log(name);
    if (name === "cost") {
      return (
        <label className="label" htmlFor={name}>
          How much do you earn per hour?
        </label>
      );
    } else if (name === "salary") {
      return (
        <label className="label" htmlFor={name}>
          How much do you want to spend?
        </label>
      );
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  };
  render() {
    console.log("this.props.nevVal", this.props.newVal);
    console.log("this.props.name", this.props.name);
    return (
      <div>
        {this.chooseLabel(this.props)}
        <input
          className="Input"
          value={this.props.newVal}
          name={this.props.name}
          placeholder={this.props.name}
          onChange={this.handleChange}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      salary: "",
      cost: "",
      tip: ""
    };
  }

  handleInputChange = (e) => {
    console.log("E.target.name", e.target.name);
    this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Input
          name="salary"
          newVal={this.state.salary}
          onInputChange={this.handleInputChange}
        />
        <Input
          name="cost"
          newVal={this.state.cost}
          onInputChange={this.handleInputChange}
        />
        <Input
          name="tip"
          newVal={this.state.tip}
          onInputChange={this.handleInputChange}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

[Link to Codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/objective-benz-u17cd?file=/src/App.js:0-1786)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When one of the inputs is changed, you update the state of your App component. And when a state of a component is updated, it re-renders, and all its children too. So all the inputs are re-rendered (and their `newVal` are logged to the console), even if you change the value of a single input.

I tried to illustrate it in the following snippet :

```js
class Input extends React.Component {
  handleChange = (e) => {
    this.props.onInputChange(e);
  };
  chooseLabel = (props) => {
    let { name } = props;
    // console.log(name);
    if (name === "cost") {
      return (
        <label className="label" htmlFor={name}>
          How much do you earn per hour?
        </label>
      );
    } else if (name === "salary") {
      return (
        <label className="label" htmlFor={name}>
          How much do you want to spend?
        </label>
      );
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  };
  render() {
    console.log(`${this.props.name} input renderd`)
    return (
      <div>
        {this.chooseLabel(this.props)}
        <input
          className="Input"
          value={this.props.newVal}
          name={this.props.name}
          placeholder={this.props.name}
          onChange={this.handleChange}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      salary: "",
      cost: "",
      tip: ""
    };
  }

  handleInputChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  };
  render() {
    console.log("App component and all its children rendered :")
    
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Input
          name="salary"
          newVal={this.state.salary}
          onInputChange={this.handleInputChange}
        />
        <Input
          name="cost"
          newVal={this.state.cost}
          onInputChange={this.handleInputChange}
        />
        <Input
          name="tip"
          newVal={this.state.tip}
          onInputChange={this.handleInputChange}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  rootElement
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Was that your question ?